# Drawing several viewports with webgl in one canvas, how to manage the html below and above it?

Tags: html, css, webgl

I'm trying to build myself a very simple framework to manage drawing content to the same webgl canvas via multiple views and react. I want to able to use the same resource in different areas of the window, so i'm trying to avoid using multiple canvases.

The end result should be something like [this example from three.js.](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=multiple#webgl_multiple_elements)

I'm pretty confused with how to manage this from the html side and am struggling to figure out if any limitations of this approach should be considered.

```
<WebGLContext.Provider value={contextState}>
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={canvasStyle} />
    {children}
</WebGLContext.Provider>
```

This is my top level wrapper. With this, i can instantiate a `<WebGLView/>` wherever and get the rectangle to be used as the "viewport" into the canvas. Just like in the example i scissor out that rect and draw some content there. Because my entire react app renders on top of this, i can put any content over that view. But... i can also obscure it. This only works if divs above it are transparent, or there is hardly any overlap between these viewports.
The view is something like:

```
<div ref={viewRef}>
  {children}
</div>
```

Another approach that i had in mind is to use react portals to manage another layer, above the canvas.

Something like this:

```
<WebGLContext.Provider value={contextState}>
    {children}
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={canvasStyle} />
    <div ref={aboveCanvasPortal}/>
</WebGLContext.Provider>
```

Since i know the rectangle of the viewport for my webgl drawing, i can manage the html above it in a similar way, draw an absolutely positioned div in it, and put some UI content in there. This also doesn't feel like it would scale very well, but i could at least have a scrollable column with a background color, a webgl view in it, and some ui on top of it. Overlapping components would probably crash this.
The view is something like:

```
<div ref={viewRef}>
  {ReactDOM.createPortal(children, aboveWebgl)
</div>
```

I've been thinking of using `toDataURL()` and then passing it as an image background to the views. This seems like it would solve the stacking/overlapping issue, and i could have a very simple html structure. But this is also a tremendous amount of overhead to add to webgl? If so, is there a way to do it cheaper, since the browser has to compose all of this somehow anyway?

Use case wise, my main use case is to use it with something like react-mosaic, where i just have a bunch of rectangles, very flat within one viewport, a div or the window. The second approach feels like it would work best. And then perhaps if i put a modal on top of that, creating another layer of below,canvas,above, html, would make sense, but like no more than that?

Answer (score 0):

When taking a deeper look into the [code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html) of the [three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=multiple#webgl_multiple_elements) you have provided, you will note, that there's just a simple `<canvas id="c"></canvas>` without any wrapping at all.

The key to your question is not to think primarily about viewports, but about [Scissor Boxes](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.4) -- as used in the aforementioned example in its [function render()](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html#L186). If you prefer (like me) to use raw WebGL instead of three.js, take a look at the MDN Doc on [WebGLRenderingContext.scissor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/scissor) and on [basic scissoring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/By_example/Basic_scissoring) as a starting point.

That should reduce the complexity of your problem and return it back to the level of (a more performant) WebGL, instead of trying to patchwork on HTML level.

Comment: I'm doing scissoring, but things get complicated conceptually when there is overlap.

Comment: I suppose you conceptually know the -- static or dynamic -- element depth order (e.g. UI stuff, what seems your main concern here, is always on top) and can such control the overlapping. What's on top has to be drawn last and is what you expose for interaction and handle via Touch/Mouse/Pointer Event API. And working with textures allows you to incorporate any image you need for your UI. That will cost some efforts (though less than patchworking, imho) but in the end it will run smoother.

Comment: I'm actually not sure how to keep track of the tree with react. When using the portal thing, the virtual tree is different from the dom tree. But your post did got me thinking in this direction. Maybe "viewport" is not what im looking for but more of a "ScissorArea". That might make it much easier to reason about conceptually. I'm thinking of something like 3ds max, it's pretty much the equivalent of creating a canvas for each window. 

Still curious about why this isn't easy to compose, by just saying `background:some-canvas` in css.